# Convert continuous image sequence to webRTC stream

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, webrtc, streaming, rtsp

I have a camera sending raw frames to my application and I need to generate a h264 stream from such frames and make it playable via browser with low latency. My idea is to use a webRTC stream in order to keep latency at minimum.

Until now my approach has been the following:

1. Use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to generate a h264/RTSP stream by means of the command

> ```
> ffmpeg -fflags nobuffer -re  -i "frames%05d.bmp" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream
> ```

2. Use [RTSP simple server](https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server) to publish the RTSP stream.
3. Use [RTSPtoWeb](https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWeb) to generate a webRTC stream playable by browsers.

   Please note input frames are 728x544 bitmaps.

Until now I had no luck: the RTSP stream produced at step (2) is playable by means of VLC but is has problems when played by means of webRTC, e.g. continuous freezes. Please note I can reproduce h264/RTSP stream produced by AXIS IP cameras by means of RTSPtoWeb with no problem.

Furthermore I'd need the frames to be passed to FFmpeg by a C# application instead of reading them from disk.

Of course if you know of a way to directly generate a h264/webRTC stream from an image sequence that would be wounderful.

Has anyone ever tried something like this?

Comment: WebRTC protocol have several limitations. The main limitation I know of, is that B-Frames are not allowed. Add `-bf 0` argument for disabling B-Frames (add it after `-c:v libx264`).

Comment: Thanks! now the stream is correctly reproduced by means of webRTC. Now I have other problems like the stream stops after a time comparable with the time ffmpeg has run, but this is likely due to the fact that I use a set of frames as test and I ciclically give them as input to ffmpeg.

Comment: You may add `-loop 1` before the `-i`.

Comment: Yep, I tried using [-stream_loop](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/repeat-loop-input-video-with-ffmpeg), however after some time the RTSPtoWeb webRTC player stops playing, while e.g. VLC play continuously.

Comment: @AlessandroMartinelli you can build WebRTC lib from sources (or use one of open source projects like Kurento simplicity) and create your own application that will get raw frames and pass them inside WebRTC lib. The lib encodes frames by itself. Refer to this C++ example: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/main/examples/peerconnection/client/ - it captures desktop screen and sends to the other peer

Comment: Thank you @ArtemSuprunov, the fact that the library is able to encode frames by itself is very good news. I'll just have to pass frames from my C# program to WebRTC Go program someway. As soon as I have time I'll definitely give it a try.

Comment: @ArtemSuprunov just to be sure: you said the lib encodes frames by itself. In which format does it encode frames? as from the original question, I need them encoded in h264 or anyway in a format with a good quality/compression ratio.

Comment: @AlessandroMartinelli codec selection is made during negotiation between two peers, when they exchange 'offer' and 'answer', i.e. the sender says which codecs he supports for encoding, the receiver - for decoding. If they both support multiple codecs, then codec is selected by preference. For instance, Google's desktop implementation between H264 and VP8 would select VP8. So, you need to set the preference by your own or filter out unwanted codecs before sending offer/answer. Btw, for H264 Google uses software OpenH264 encoder. On Android and iOS they use HW encoders on that platforms.